# Finding the most "uniform" or "least concentrated" density function, subject to moment constraints

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, optimization, prior

### **Background**

I want to find a probability measure for a continuous random variable, subject to moment constraints, that is maximally "uniform", as defined below:

---

**Definition: Maximally Uniform Probability Measure**

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability measure defined on $\mathcal{D}_X=\mathcal{B}([a,b])$, and let $L_m=\{B \in \mathcal{D}_X: \lambda(B)=m\}$, where $\lambda(B)$ is the Lebesgue measure of Borel set $B$ and $0\leq m \leq \lambda([a,b])$. Let $C$ be a set of constraints on the probability measure of $X$, and $\mathcal{P}_C$ be the class of all continuous probability measures on $\mathcal{D}_X$ that satisfy $C$.

For given constraints $C$, a maximally uniform probability measure $P^*_X \in \mathcal{P}_C$  achieves the *minimum* **maximum** probability measure for **every** $L_m$, where minimization is over $\mathcal{P}_C$.

Specifically, for a set of constraints $C$ and associated probability measures $\mathcal{P}_C$, the maximally uniform probability measure $P^*_X \in \mathcal{P}_C$ satisfies the following condition:

$\left\{\max\limits_{B\in L_m}{P^*_X(B)}\leq \max\limits_{B\in L_m}{P_X(B)}\;\; \forall m\right\}\forall P_X \in \mathcal{P}_C$

---

For example, if I specify the class of Borel sets of Lebesgue measure 3 (i.e., $L_3$), and pick a probability measure from $P \in \mathcal{P}_C$ then I would proceed to find the interval in $L_3$ that has the **highest** probability measure wrt $P$. If $P$ is maximally uniform, then when I do this exercise for any other $P' \in \mathcal{P}_C$, I will get a Borel set of Lebesgue measure 3 that contains *more* probability than $P$. This will be also be the case for any other class of Borel sets of given Lebesgue measure (i.e., there is nothing special about 3).

My thinking is that I can solve this problem as a variational optimization problem (at least for $-\infty < a\leq b,< \infty)$, by minimizing the **path length** of the distribution function $F$ associated with each $P_X \in \mathcal{P}_C$.

Below is the formulation of my problem as a variational-calculus problem Note: $f(x)=F'(x)=$ target density function associated with the maximally uniform probability measure.

$\min\limits_{f(x)} \int\limits_a^b \sqrt{1+f(x)^2} dx$

$s.t.$

$\int\limits_a^b f(x) dx = 1$

$\int\limits_a^b xf(x) dx = 0$

$\int\limits_a^b x^if(x) dx = a_i \;\;i\in \{S \subset \mathbb{N^+}/1\}$

$f(x) \geq 0$

Using the euler-lagrange euqations, I have solved the general formulation of the above to get the following **implicit** solution:

$\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{{f(x)}^{2}+1}}= \sum\limits_{i\in S \cup \{0,1\}}\mu_i{x}^{i}$ where the $\mu_i$ are the langrange multipliers (one per constraint) that must be solved for to make this implicit solution satisfy the constraints.

---

### What I need help with

In order of priority (I will accept any answer that addresses either of these):

1. Is there an **explicit** solution of the above? (even if it uses infinite series)
2. Does the concept of uniformity via path length minimization admit pathological cases (in the continuous measure case only)?

Comment: There seem to be several rather different questions here: are you asking how to (a) find a "maximally uniform" measure, (b) whether it has any connection with the length functional, or (c) how to minimize the length functional?

Comment: @whuber thanks for your interest and questions. I will edit my post to make it clearer what I am asking.

Comment: @whuber an explicit solution to (c) in your comment would be most helpful. However, any comments/problems with (a) and (b) would also be useful - it makes sense to me, but I may be missing something...I was looking for an alternative to max. entropy that actually has concrete probabilistic implications.